# web automation from perl

Tags: perl, webautomation

I am looking for a web page automation tool in Perl. I want to be able to drive different browsers like IE, firefox etc from my test script. 
I have to automate a product web page with lots of input fields and loads of javascript. I do not want a custom browser like mechanize does. 
I used  to work with Ruby before and there I used Watir. Is there something similar in Perl?

Comment: Tell us something about Watir?  What does "custom browser" (that you don't want) mean?

Comment: Watir is used for automating existing web browsers. It is not a web browser in itself. It drives the other web browsers. My requirement is to check compatibility with the available web browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Selenium-RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) with [WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Selenium) could be what you're looking for. Tim Brockman has written about setting it up here: [Selenium and Perl = tears of joy](http://timbrockman.com/2010/02/selenium-and-perl-tears-of-joy/)

Answer (score 4):

- [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox)
- Win32::IE::Mechanize ([Module no longer exists.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1061372))

Comment: Thanks, but Mechanize does not support Javascript. The web page(s) that I need to automate are fully dynamic and use a lot of javascript.
http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.64/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#I_have_this_web_page_that_has_JavaScript_on_it,_and_my_Mech_program_doesn't_work.

Comment: WWW::Mechanize doesn't but the two modules I linked to do.